# How do I get rid of extra "group by" column in when using a CASE statement in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a table in SQL Server that combines a customers aggregate activity into a single row.

For example, Customer A has 2 membership orders and 3 event orders. Right now my query is resulting in 2 rows. One that shows the Customer A with 2 membership orders and 0 event orders and another that shows 0 membership orders and 3 event orders.

How can I create a query that will just create one row that looks like? I think the problem is that I have to include `subsystem` and `fulfill_status_code` in the `group by` statement.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
select ship_master_customer_id,
CASE WHEN subsystem = 'MBR' AND fulfill_status_code != 'c' THEN count(order_no) ELSE null END as membership_orders,
CASE WHEN subsystem = 'MBR' AND fulfill_status_code != 'c' THEN sum(actual_total_amount) ELSE null END as membership_amount,
CASE WHEN subsystem = 'MTG' AND fulfill_status_code != 'c'THEN sum(actual_total_amount) ELSE null END as event_orders,
CASE WHEN subsystem = 'MTG' AND fulfill_status_code != 'c'THEN count(order_no) ELSE null END as event_amount
from order_detail od (nolock)
where invoice_date>'5/1/2015'

group by ship_master_customer_id, subsystem, fulfill_status_code
```

Comment: `How can I create a query that will just create one row that looks like? I think the problem is that I have to include subsystem and fulfill_status_code in the group by statement.`  So what is exactly your question?

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select ship_master_customer_id,
-- This is a "fake count":  the value is 1 when your condition is true, and we
-- add up all the 1's.
SUM( CASE WHEN subsystem = 'MBR' AND fulfill_status_code != 'c' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as membership_orders,
SUM( CASE WHEN subsystem = 'MBR' AND fulfill_status_code != 'c' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as membership_amount,
SUM( CASE WHEN subsystem = 'MTG' AND fulfill_status_code != 'c' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as event_orders,
SUM( CASE WHEN subsystem = 'MTG' AND fulfill_status_code != 'c' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as event_amount

from order_detail od (nolock)
where invoice_date>'5/1/2015'

group by ship_master_customer_id
```

There are lots of other ways to do it, as well.

Comment: This is empirically true.

Answer (score 0):

You almost always don't want the sum or count in a case statement, instead put the case statement in the sum.

```
select ship_master_customer_id,
SUM( CASE WHEN subsystem = 'MBR' AND fulfill_status_code != 'c' AND order_no is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS membership_orders,
SUM( CASE WHEN subsystem = 'MBR' AND fulfill_status_code != 'c' THEN actual_total_amount ELSE 0 END) AS membership_amount,
SUM( CASE WHEN subsystem = 'MTG' AND fulfill_status_code != 'c' THEN actual_total_amount ELSE 0 END) AS event_orders,
SUM( CASE WHEN subsystem = 'MTG' AND fulfill_status_code != 'c' AND order_no is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS event_amount
from order_detail od (nolock)
where invoice_date > '5/1/2015'
group by ship_master_customer_id
```